# Create template pages

Tags: views, nodes, theming, 7

Using Drupal 7 and Clean theme. And my main module is Views. And i want, create template tpl.php file for every page.

I know node id method but don't know how create tpl file for views pages.

Please help, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the views ui, click on 'advanced' and go to 'theme information'. This gives you a number of suggestions for the template file and what code should be in it.

Comment: My views display output: views-view--news.tpl.php  Now, i must put this file in templates directory?

Comment: yep, '/sites/all/themes/YOUR_THEME/templates'.

Comment: Sorry but not working. i want change header img every page. So, i want views id but not working.

Comment: be sure to use the Rescan button in the Views UI > Theme information

Comment: You want to override the page template to change the header. Probably not going to do this with views.